# quiz about local minimum and maximum

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, maxima-minima

I am student learning *calculus*, and have got stuck on one of calculus quiz

the quiz gives the equation,
$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = x\sin{x}-\cos{x}$ for $0<x<4$

and ask for $x$ location of local maximum.

so my solution process was to find out $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=0$, so that

1. $x\sin{x}=\cos x$
2. $\tan{x}=\frac{1}{x}$
3. $\arctan{\frac{1}{x}} = x$
4. derivative both side
5. It turns out $x^2 = -2$.

I guess making simple mistakes here, which i can't find out
would be grateful if someone can help me out.

Comment: $\tan=\frac{\sin}{\cos}$

Comment: oops typo, i just edited

Comment: Your error is in step 3: since $\arctan(\tan (3))=3-\pi,$ then $\arctan(\tan x)\not\equiv x.$